# Symfony4 new bundle autoloading

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, autoload, symfony4

I want to create a new reusable bundle with SF4. I followed the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html#creating-a-bundle) but if I add my new bundle inside the "src" directory, there is a conflict with the App namespace and composer autoloading:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Acme\\TestBundle\\": "src/Acme/TestBundle/"
    }
},
```

Then, I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "AcmeTestBundle" from namespace "Acme\TestBundle".

I think it's because the PSR-4 autoloader loaded the file with the wrong namespace (App/Acme/TestBundle/AcmeTestBundle.php).

Is there a way to fix this issue? I've also tried to create another bundle for my App but then it crash because of the Kernel.php file...

This fallback directory method doesn't work either:

```
"psr-4": {
    "": "src/"
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue. Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes I've done that too. Did you follow the documentation instructions? Did you use the Symfony 4 version?

Comment: Is your directory structure src/Acme/TestBundle or just src/TestBundle?

Comment: Yes, I was able to create the AcmeTestBundle in my Symfony 4 app as per the documentation, using the same PSR-4 autoload config you’re using. Other things to check: is the class named correctly? Are all files and paths named correctly? Does the class have the correct namespace declaration at the top of the file?

Comment: And what does "but then it crash because of the Kernel.php file..." mean?  Sounds like you have something else going on.

Comment: If I use the fallback directory method in composer.json, I get PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App".

Comment: Now I get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Acme\TestBundle\AcmeTestBundle, because the name is already in use in /var/www/sf-test/src/Acme/TestBundle/AcmeTestBundle.php on line 10

Comment: @Cerad It is src/Acme/TestBundle

Comment: Add Acme to the list of excluded directories in config/services.yaml to get rid of the "name already in use" message.

Comment: @Cerad Looks like it solved the problem! Could you add your answer so I can validate it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pjehan please add that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help PSR-4 Autoloader to load Acme as a bundle, you must exclude his 
directory from App services directories :

file: config/services.yaml

```
services:
        ...
        App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        **exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Repository,Acme}'**
```